# Insert Row Into MongoDB using 3T Studio

Tags: mongodb

I have a quick question that maybe someone can help me with. I am fairly new to MongoDB and I made it pretty far on my own so far.

I have created a database that contains all my employees, emails, job titles.

I uploaded these from a CSV file but the CSV file is pretty huge to edit. I was wondering if there a way I can insert a row into it so I can label them such as: Name:Email:Title

I havent been able to figure this out and any help would be great.

Comment: Needs more details , what are we looking at here . The data is loaded or not ?

Comment: The data is loaded. I have uploaded them via CSV import.

Comment: And now you want to write to the db ?

Comment: Sorry I understand what you are saying now.

The database is already created and all the names, emails and titles are in there. 
I just need to add a row to the very top that says Name:Email:Title

Comment: so you mean a header row with the name of the columns ? that would be a static row at the top of the table where these fields are presented and not part of the data itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you could do something like this :

```
    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

    $insRec = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

    $insRec->insert(['name' =>'Max CodeSmith', 'email'=>'info@maxcodesmith.com', 'title'=>'Solutions Architect']);

    $writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 1000);

    $result = $manager->executeBulkWrite('your.collection', $insRec, $writeConcern);
```